# Переваги та недоліки вживання запозичених слів, які мають українські відповідники?

Tags: вживання-слів, запозичені-слова, іншомовні-слова

Які є переваги та недоліки використання запозичених слів, коли існують загальновживані відповідники української мови? Чи варто намагатися вживати лише питомо українські слова?

Приклади таких слів:

- Індиферентний — Байдужий.
- Заангажований — Упереджений.

Comment: Багато на тему можна знайти в [передньому слові](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/perednye-slovo) до *Як ми говоримо*

Answer (score 4):

Зазвичай питомі (українські) слова мають ширше значення, аніж запозичені.
Ваші приклади також не є абсолютними синонімами.

Індиферентний вживається в першу чергу як наукове означення речовин чи явищ, тоді як байдужим може бути в принципі будь-що.

Заангажована стаття - упереджена на користь когось чи чогось, зазвичай політичної сили. Просто упереджена стаття - автор, наприклад, використовує занадто багато стереотипів.

Варто вживати слова, які максимально точно передають необхідне значення і підходять за стилем. Чи це слово питомо українське, чи запозичене - це вже як вийде.

Однозначно точно не треба використовувати слова іншомовного походження, якщо є наш відповідник, який ідеально підходить. Наприклад, у більшості випадків слово "розробник" чудово замінює слово "девелопер", проте останнє доводиться чути і бачити дуже часто.

Також часто люди можуть використовувати якесь іншомовне слово, бо воно відчувається більш престижним, більш високого стилю. Це може з часом призводити до повного витіснення питомого українського, і запозичене слово набуває ширшого значення. Таких ситуацій теж варто уникати.

Схожі думки викладені, наприклад, [тут](http://linguistics-konspect.org/?content=2433) чи [тут](https://www.kadrovik.ua/novyny/chy-dorechno-vzhyvaty-u-dilovodstvi-inshomovni-slova).

Comment: Статті, на які ви посилаєтесь, не мають посилань на джерела, розміщені на не дуже авторитетних ресурсах, мають одруки в собі. Волів би проголосувати за цю відповідь, але не можу через якість джерел.

Comment: Я погоджуюся з тим, що джерела у мене так собі. Тому не бачу нічого страшного у тому, що за відповідь не буде проголосовано.

Comment: Теж позиція. Дякую, що спробували пошукати.

Answer (score 4):

Я загалом згоден з [xpoback](/a/6051).

Я ще не аналізував конкретно *індиферентний*/*байдужий* і *заангажований*/*упереджений*, але загалом доволі часто слова іншомовного походження, що з'являються в українській мові паралельно з українськими аналогами, отримують вужче чи просто трішки інше значення. Наприклад:

- *Абревіатура* — це не просто *скорочення* (тобто це частковий випадок скорочення, але не будь-яке скорочення — абревіатура).
- *Анонс* — це не просто *оголошення* (нагадую, що в українській мові анонс — це *попереднє* оголошення).
- *Чізкейк* — це не просто *сирник* (традиційний сирник — це дещо інше, ніж те, що зараз називають чізкейком; хоча якщо брати слово «сирник» у дуже широкому розумінні, то чізкейк можна вважати різновидом сирника, але виникає потреба якось називати отой частковий різновид).

Хоча я не заперечую, що часто слова запозичуються не задля специфічного значення, а через лінощі (після багатьох обговорень якоїсь теми іноземною простіше продовжувати обговорювати її українською, не змінюючи термінологію) і/або пиху (мовляв, «солідніше звучить») (що цікаво, навіть у цьому випадку слова *з часом* можуть *набувати* дещо іншого значення).

Утім, на мою думку, не варто намагатися брати за правило викорінити всі запозичення, для яких начебто є українські відповідники, бо:

- часто запозичені слова мають дещо інше значення (тобто в певних випадках передають суть точніше); і людина, що не є професіоналом у відповідній галузі, може не розуміти цього;
- ми не можемо силоміць повернути розвиток мови в інший напрямок (якщо, припустімо, певний англіцизм уживається *лише* через моду, то шкода, але набридаючи іншим із «кажи так-то, а не так-то», можна досягти лише погіршення стосунків, а не зміни звичок оточення);
- іноді справді необхідно створити певний стиль/антураж/атмосферу й уживання «нестандартних» слів може бути в нагоді.

Переваги застосування власних (чи давно засвоєних) слів (якщо вони точно передають суть і не надто довші за запозичені відповідники), по-моєму, очевидні — логічніше, коли ми схожі за значеннями слова утворюємо від одного кореня (наприклад: *купувати*, *покупний*, *закупки*), а не від різних (наприклад: *купувати*, *покупний*, *шопінг*), а це в свою чергу:

- робить мову простішою для розуміння;
- зменшує простір для омонімії (чим менше різних коренів припадає на одне й те саме значення, тим менша кількість коренів потрібна загалом для всіх слів і тим менша ймовірність часткового чи повного збігу коренів із різними значеннями).